# '"aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value' crash when I add a raw resource folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application (gradle 2.1.0, SDK level 22) that includes an AAR. Everything works fine until I add a resource in res/raw in the main application, then I get this crash on running assembleDebug:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\SDK\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819
```

The exact command that fails is:

```
E:\Android\SDK\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I E:\Android\SDK\platforms\android-22\android.jar -M E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -A E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.oovoo.sdk.oovoosdksampleshow -0 apk --output-text-symbols E:\Morganarium\MercenaryTech\FogCity\CoreV2\androidVS2015\FCL\OovooTest\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
```

There's no error just a hard crash in aapt.exe

Some of the other threads on this suggest it's caused by a clash between files in the main application and the merged AAR. But there is no res/raw folder in the included AAR, and the crash happens even if I put a dummy "foo.txt" resource in res/raw (and goes away if I delete res/raw).

Any thoughts?  Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the latest build tools?

For me I use the latest one 23.0.3 or 24.0.1 and its work

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use the latest one for build tools. You have to change the line  buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X" in **build.gradle** file (which generally resides under **mobile** directory in gradle 2.0) to the latest version : 23.0.2 or 25.0.2. And then **Rebuild Project**. If you still have an issue, please try to update the corresponding build tool via **Android SDK Manager**.

Comment: I don't think this answer has anything to do with the question at hand. Can you show why you think this will help with the problem as described?

Comment: @jdv: This is a general problem for aapt crashing with or without new resource adding.. I have faced this issue numerous times for various reasons.. This solution gave me the desired result.

Comment: Seems unlikely that upgrading, itself, is the solution. Rather, some people found a bug in some version of the build tools. Arbitrarily upgrading build tools can just as easily reveal other bugs or incompatibilities -- it is technically a functional change.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the built tools version, changing version in gradle 
**app/gradle**

Setting :

> **buildToolsVersion** **"25.0.2"**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vastinfos.android.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}